# How to count the number of NEW ids in hive SQL table by date?

Tags: sql, hive, count, window-functions

I have a table with a bunch of months and ids. I want to count how many NEW ids I've gotten in each month. For example, say I have the following table:

```
Month | ID
------------
Jan   | 123
Jan   | 456
Jan   | 789
Feb   | 123
Feb   | 101112
Mar   | 456
Mar   | 12345
Mar   | 6789
```

I want the output to be:

```
Month | # New IDS
------------------
Jan   | 3
Feb   | 1
Mar   | 2
```

I'm truly lost on the best way to do this and haven't been able to find anything that's similar to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses two levels of aggregation. Assuming that `month` is of a `date` datatype (or at least something that can be consistently sorted as a date):

```
select month, count(*) new_ids
from (select min(month) month from mytable group by id) t
group by month
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select month, count(*) new_ids
from (
    select month, row_number() over(partition by id order by month) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
```